# "This plug-in will make contributions to the UI" option - behavior and explanation

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-3.5

Does the option "**This plug-in will make contributions to the UI**" essentially get ignored if the previous option "**Generate an activator, a Java class that controls the plug-in's life cycle"** is NOT selected" ?

[alt text http://img179.imageshack.us/img179/6710/newpluginoptions.png](http://img179.imageshack.us/img179/6710/newpluginoptions.png)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, yes - it is ignored in that circumstance.

The "**This plug-in will make contributions to the UI**" toggle controls two things:

1) Which class the auto generated Activator class extends (see further explanation below).

2) The list of available templates to choose from on the "**Next>**" page of the wizard.

But if the first option isn't selected, neither of these are applicable. Almost seems like a bit of a form logic bug. The UI should ideally conditionally enable/disable the second toggle. Oh well...

---

If set to ON, Activator extends **org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin**

if set to OFF, Activator extends **org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin**

Answer (score 1):

It is ignored.
This is a vestige from the pre-OSGi area, where you could develop a plugin making contribution to Eclipse UI without needing an Activator: see **[Eclipse Extension vs. OSGi services](https://www.eclipsezone.com//articles/extensions-vs-services/)**.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipsezone.com](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/extensions-vs-services/images/extensions.png))</sub>

(No Activator there)